# How to add progress indicator in shape of image layout in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
 ClipRRect(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
                                            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              width: 78.w,
                                              height: 78.h,
                                              imageUrl: controller
                                                      .userProductsList[i]
                                                      .product
                                                      ?.image ??
                                                  "",
                                              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                  const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                            )),
```

So, I have used cacheNetworkimage to load image. but as placeholder I have load circle progress indicator. but it is showing loading bar in circle shape. How to set according image layout with radius. Banana image is my image shape

Answer (score 0):

For a very quick solution you could use [square_percent_indicater](https://pub.dev/packages/square_percent_indicater) from `pub.dev`. I have seen it being used in a project and had to replace it because it wasn't very smooth, and replaced it with drawing the loading lines into a canvas, but that's another story :).
For the solution I went with, you'd need to fiddle with Drawing to the canvas and stuff, I don't think you'll have anything ready made, except if there are packages that do this in pub.dev.